# Storyshots testing with all the knobs options

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storyshots

How to generate snapshots for all possible knob options? Right now storybook with storyshots and jest can make screenshots only for default component state, which doesn't cover all possible variants.

I understand that there's a possible way by creating stories for all the knob options but that defats the purpose of having knobs in the first place.

Is there any way to do this?

Originally mentioned in a comment on github: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4103#issuecomment-426217161